# Why isn't my ribbon button icon showing?

Tags: c#, button, icons, ribbon, revit-api

I've created a button to add to the Revit ribbon, under the `Modify` tab, under the `Properties` tab.  The button shows up and functions without a problem.  The only issue that we've encountered is that the icon for the button will not display.  We've tried several approaches to remedy this issue, but nothing seems to work.

### Code:

```
Autodesk.Windows.RibbonControl pRibbon = Autodesk.Windows.ComponentManager.Ribbon;
foreach (var pTab in pRibbon.Tabs)
{
    if (pTab.Id == "Modify")
    {
        foreach (var pPanel in pTab.Panels)
        {
            if (pPanel.Source.Id == "properties_shr")
            {
                // Add button.
                pIcon = Properties.Resources.AS_Revit_UI_Taps_Tees32x32.GetHbitmap();
                var pBtn = CreatePanelButton(pIcon, "Taps/Tees", "id_astapteebutton", "Taps/Tees", 32, 32);

                Autodesk.Windows.ComponentManager.UIElementActivated += RunSwitchTapTee;
                pPanel.Source.Items.Add(pBtn);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

public Autodesk.Windows.RibbonButton CreatePanelButton(IntPtr pIcon, string sBtnName, string sID, string sText, int iHeight, int iWidth)
{
    var pBtn = new Autodesk.Windows.RibbonButton()
    {
        Name = sBtnName,
        Image = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(pIcon, IntPtr.Zero, System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromWidthAndHeight(32, 32)),
        Id = sID,
        AllowInStatusBar = true,
        AllowInToolBar = true,
        GroupLocation = Autodesk.Private.Windows.RibbonItemGroupLocation.Middle,
        MinHeight = 0,
        MinWidth = 0,
        Height = iHeight,
        Width = iWidth,
        IsEnabled = true,
        IsVisible = true,
        IsCheckable = true,
        ShowImage = true,
        ShowText = true,
        Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical,
        Text = sText,
        Size = Autodesk.Windows.RibbonItemSize.Large,
        ResizeStyle = Autodesk.Windows.RibbonItemResizeStyles.HideText
    };

    return pBtn;
}
```

The result is this:

[image]

As you can see, the button is placed.  It works as intended.  It just wont show the icon...  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that my error was in the setting of the `Image`.  I wrote:

```
Image = System.Windows.Interop....
.
.
.
Size = Autodesk.Windows.RibbonItemSize.Large,
```

I needed to adjust one or the other - either `Image` to `LargeImage` **or** `RibbonItemSize.Large` to `RibbonItemSize.Standard`...

It would only make sense that large images need large sizes, and standard images need standard sizes.

### What's the difference?

In Revit, your ribbon buttons can either be 16x16 pixels (standard) or 32x32 pixels (large).  Depending on your desired UI layout will help you decide which you need.